# Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView

Tags: java, android

I got an error while rendering the view:

2022-04-20 10:46:55.361 9871-9871/? I/trolink.whatsU: Late-enabling -Xcheck:jni
2022-04-20 10:46:55.396 9871-9871/? E/trolink.whatsU: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x8000
2022-04-20 10:46:57.347 9871-9871/com.strolink.whatsUp I/Perf: Connecting to perf service.
2022-04-20 10:46:57.367 9871-9871/com.strolink.whatsUp I/MultiDex: VM with version 2.1.0 has multidex support
2022-04-20 10:46:57.367 9871-9871/com.strolink.whatsUp I/MultiDex: Installing application
2022-04-20 10:46:57.367 9871-9871/com.strolink.whatsUp I/MultiDex: VM has multidex support, MultiDex support library is disabled.
2022-04-20 10:46:57.424 9871-9871/com.strolink.whatsUp I/FeatureParser: can't find olive.xml in assets/device_features/,it may be in /system/etc/device_features
2022-04-20 10:46:57.520 9871-9871/com.strolink.whatsUp V/FA: Registered activity lifecycle callback
2022-04-20 10:46:57.523 9871-9871/com.strolink.whatsUp D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth is not linked. Skipping initialization.
2022-04-20 10:46:57.524 9871-9871/com.strolink.whatsUp D/FirebaseApp: com.google.firebase.crash.FirebaseCrash is not linked. Skipping initialization.
2022-04-20 10:46:57.525 9871-9871/com.strolink.whatsUp I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
2022-04-20 10:46:57.613 9871-9914/com.strolink.whatsUp V/FA: Collection enabled
2022-04-20 10:46:57.614 9871-9914/com.strolink.whatsUp V/FA: App package, google app id: com.strolink.whatsUp, 1:957242236730:android:6ace47f1a2067c79db3a03
2022-04-20 10:46:57.616 9871-9914/com.strolink.whatsUp I/FA: App measurement is starting up, version: 16250
2022-04-20 10:46:57.616 9871-9914/com.strolink.whatsUp I/FA: To enable debug logging run: adb shell setprop log.tag.FA VERBOSE
2022-04-20 10:46:57.616 9871-9914/com.strolink.whatsUp I/FA: To enable faster debug mode event logging run:
adb shell setprop debug.firebase.analytics.app com.strolink.whatsUp
2022-04-20 10:46:57.617 9871-9914/com.strolink.whatsUp D/FA: Debug-level message logging enabled
2022-04-20 10:46:57.681 9871-9914/com.strolink.whatsUp V/FA: Connecting to remote service
2022-04-20 10:46:57.724 9871-9914/com.strolink.whatsUp V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
2022-04-20 10:46:57.775 9871-9925/com.strolink.whatsUp D/NetworkSecurityConfig: No Network Security Config specified, using platform default
2022-04-20 10:46:57.776 9871-9925/com.strolink.whatsUp I/DpmTcmClient: RegisterTcmMonitor from: $Proxy0
2022-04-20 10:46:57.906 9871-9871/com.strolink.whatsUp W/Looper: Slow Looper main: Long Msg: seq=2 plan=۱۰:۴۶:۵۵.۴۴۰  late=2ms wall=2463ms running=0ms h=android.app.ActivityThread$H w=110
2022-04-20 10:46:57.907 9871-9934/com.strolink.whatsUp E/Perf: Fail to get file list com.strolink.whatsUp
2022-04-20 10:46:57.907 9871-9934/com.strolink.whatsUp E/Perf: getFolderSize() : Exception_1 = java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
2022-04-20 10:46:58.001 9871-9871/com.strolink.whatsUp V/FA: onActivityCreated
2022-04-20 10:46:58.035 9871-9871/com.strolink.whatsUp D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: com.strolink.whatsUp activity: com.strolink.whatsUp.activities.welcome.IntroActivity@80a4d
2022-04-20 10:46:58.040 9871-9871/com.strolink.whatsUp D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: com.strolink.whatsUp activity: com.strolink.whatsUp.activities.welcome.IntroActivity@80a4d
2022-04-20 10:46:58.050 9871-9871/com.strolink.whatsUp I/chatty: uid=10250(com.strolink.whatsUp) identical 2 lines
2022-04-20 10:46:58.052 9871-9871/com.strolink.whatsUp D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: com.strolink.whatsUp activity: com.strolink.whatsUp.activities.welcome.IntroActivity@80a4d
2022-04-20 10:46:58.064 9871-9871/com.strolink.whatsUp W/trolink.whatsU: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2022-04-20 10:46:58.065 9871-9871/com.strolink.whatsUp W/trolink.whatsU: Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
2022-04-20 10:46:58.069 9871-9871/com.strolink.whatsUp D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: com.strolink.whatsUp activity: com.strolink.whatsUp.activities.welcome.IntroActivity@80a4d
2022-04-20 10:46:58.073 9871-9871/com.strolink.whatsUp D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: com.strolink.whatsUp activity: com.strolink.whatsUp.activities.welcome.IntroActivity@80a4d
2022-04-20 10:46:58.077 9871-9871/com.strolink.whatsUp I/chatty: uid=10250(com.strolink.whatsUp) identical 2 lines
2022-04-20 10:46:58.087 9871-9871/com.strolink.whatsUp D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: com.strolink.whatsUp activity: com.strolink.whatsUp.activities.welcome.IntroActivity@80a4d
2022-04-20 10:46:58.100 9871-9871/com.strolink.whatsUp D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: com.strolink.whatsUp activity: com.strolink.whatsUp.activities.welcome.IntroActivity@80a4d
2022-04-20 10:46:58.103 9871-9871/com.strolink.whatsUp I/chatty: uid=10250(com.strolink.whatsUp) identical 1 line
2022-04-20 10:46:58.104 9871-9871/com.strolink.whatsUp D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: com.strolink.whatsUp activity: com.strolink.whatsUp.activities.welcome.IntroActivity@80a4d
2022-04-20 10:46:58.106 9871-9871/com.strolink.whatsUp D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: com.strolink.whatsUp activity: com.strolink.whatsUp.activities.welcome.IntroActivity@80a4d
2022-04-20 10:46:58.109 9871-9871/com.strolink.whatsUp I/chatty: uid=10250(com.strolink.whatsUp) identical 3 lines
2022-04-20 10:46:58.112 9871-9871/com.strolink.whatsUp D/ForceDarkHelper: updateByCheckExcludeList: pkg: com.strolink.whatsUp activity: com.strolink.whatsUp.activities.welcome.IntroActivity@80a4d
2022-04-20 10:46:58.117 9871-9871/com.strolink.whatsUp D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM

```
--------- beginning of crash
```

2022-04-20 10:46:58.121 9871-9871/com.strolink.whatsUp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.strolink.whatsUp, PID: 9871
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.strolink.whatsUp/com.strolink.whatsUp.activities.welcome.IntroActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #83 in com.strolink.whatsUp:layout/activity_intro_layout: Binary XML file line #83 in com.strolink.whatsUp:layout/activity_intro_layout: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3308)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3457)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2044)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #83 in com.strolink.whatsUp:layout/activity_intro_layout: Binary XML file line #83 in com.strolink.whatsUp:layout/activity_intro_layout: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #83 in com.strolink.whatsUp:layout/activity_intro_layout: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:858)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1010)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:965)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1127)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1130)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1088)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:686)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:538)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:481)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:696)
at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:170)
at com.strolink.whatsUp.activities.welcome.IntroActivity.onCreate(IntroActivity.java:96)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7906)
at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:7893)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1307)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3283)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3457)
at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2044)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7562)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
2022-04-20 10:46:58.122 9871-9871/com.strolink.whatsUp E/AndroidRuntime:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
Caused by: java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index=0 out of bounds (limit=0, nb=4)
at java.nio.Buffer.checkIndex(Buffer.java:564)
at java.nio.DirectByteBuffer.getInt(DirectByteBuffer.java:570)
at android.graphics.fonts.FontFileUtil.analyzeStyle(FontFileUtil.java:94)
at android.graphics.fonts.Font$Builder.build(Font.java:364)
at android.graphics.Typeface$Builder.build(Typeface.java:606)
at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.loadFont(ResourcesImpl.java:1004)
at android.content.res.Resources.getFont(Resources.java:414)
at android.content.res.TypedArray.getFont(TypedArray.java:1037)
at android.widget.TextView.readTextAppearance(TextView.java:3999)
at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:1064)
at android.widget.TextView.(TextView.java:968)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:100)
at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView.(AppCompatTextView.java:95)
... 30 more
2022-04-20 10:46:58.146 9871-9871/com.strolink.whatsUp I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 9871 SIG: 9

activity_intro_layout :

```
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorWhite">

        <FrameLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="top"
            android:layout_marginTop="88dp">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_image1"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_logo_circle"
                android:padding="26dp"
                android:src="@drawable/intro1" />

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/icon_image2"
                android:layout_width="120dp"
                android:layout_height="120dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_logo_circle"
                android:padding="6dp" />

        </FrameLayout>

        <androidx.viewpager.widget.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/intro_view_pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />


        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/bottom_pages"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            android:orientation="horizontal">

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="8dp"
                android:layout_height="8dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_indicator" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="8dp"
                android:layout_height="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_indicator" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="8dp"
                android:layout_height="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_indicator" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="8dp"
                android:layout_height="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_indicator" />

            <FrameLayout
                android:layout_width="8dp"
                android:layout_height="8dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="7dp"
                android:background="@drawable/bg_indicator" />


        </LinearLayout>

        <androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatTextView
            android:id="@+id/get_started_button"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:visibility="gone"
            android:text="@string/get_started"
            android:textColor="@color/colorWhite"
            android:textSize="18sp" />
    </RelativeLayout>

</ScrollView>
```

I found that it works well on the emulator with api 26. But on Android 10 (and maybe higher than Android 10) it gives this error

Comment: Can you post the `activity_intro_layout` XML code?

Answer (score 0):

Please check your texview ID in xml and your given ID in java file

Comment: Thank you for your answer
I checked again But it gives the same error.
codes build.gradle:
android {
     compileSdkVersion 30
     buildToolsVersion '30 .0.3 '

     defaultConfig {
         applicationId "com.strolink.whatsUp"
         minSdkVersion 21
         targetSdkVersion 30
         versionCode 9
         versionName "1.0.8"
         multiDexEnabled true
         vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
         testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
         renderscriptTargetApi 30
         renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true


     }

Comment: can you resolve problem javad?